# Is is possible to authenticate against IBM MQ server using a certificate in the MQ connector within Azure Logic apps?

Tags: azure, ibm-mq, azure-logic-apps

I want to use the MQ Connector which is available in Logic App to connect to an IBM MQ Server. I know this works well without using a certificate.

But now I have an MQ server to connect to and I must use a certificate to connect to that MQ Server.

Can I use a certificate for this instance? If so. Any ideas how to set that up?

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the workarounds that you can try.
Try checking the Use TLS from your Single Tenant Logic app

[image]

Before adding the connection try navigating to `Configurations` from the left side pane of the Logic App and then add `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE`, and set the value to `1`.

[image]

[image]

You can add your certificates either through TLS/SSL settings or TLS/SSL settings(preview) from the left pane of your logic app

[image]

Add your certificates through preview enables you to add the certicate using any of the following options:

1. Create App Service Managed Certificate
2. Import App service Certificate
3. Upload Certificate
4. Import from key vault

[image]

You can also refer to these similar issue threads [Thread 1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47142) and [Thread 2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/21763).

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Call service endpoints by using HTTP or HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#authentication-for-single-tenant-environment)
2. [Secure access and data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-securing-a-logic-app?tabs=azure-portal#access-for-outbound-calls-to-other-services-and-systems)